# deviceready event breaks after upgrading to cordova 2.2.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

In IOS after upgrading from cordova 2.1.0 to 2.2.0 the deviceready event doesn't fire anymore.
Anybody else having this problem?

```
var onDeviceReady = function() {
    device_ready = true;
    alert('dev ready');
    initApp();
};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Anybody else have this problem?

Comment: I have a similar problem, which suggests a problem in Cordova-2.2.0. Steps to repeat : 1. Create new Cordova-2.2.0 project using ios/bin/create. 2. Run in the iPad 5.? or iPhone 5.? <em>simulators</em> 3. The "Connecting to Device" message keeps blinking - No Deviceready event is received. My actual app works fine on a <em>physical</em> iPad (5.0), and on the iPhone (5.?) simulators, but in the iPad 5.? simulators does not receive the deviceready event either. I am on a MacBook Air, Mountain Lion, Xcode 4.5.2, Cordova-2.2.0, all freshly installed.

Comment: Gary, the google analytics plugin for phonegap was causing my problem.  I didn't look into it too much because I decided to use flurry instead. Are you using the ga plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the position of the code. I had the similar issue and changing the position of the code and also calling the .addEventListener, body onLoad event solved the issue.

```
function onLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

var onDeviceReady = function() {
    device_ready = true;
    alert('dev ready');
    initApp();
};

....

<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Also try to check you plugins.xml and config.xml, it is possible that there are some deprecated properties in the new version.

Would it be possible for you to post the logs as well?